# Forward domain to url with different port

Tags: redirect, dns, forwarding

I have a domain: `example.com`

I would like to forward this (with a mask) to `192.168.1.1:1234/page.html`

Can I achieve this with normal domain forwarding? (ie. with godaddy)

Comment: Did you try adding `192.168.1.1:1234/page.html` as a forwarding destination in godaddy?

Comment: Yes I have tried that, and it didn't work